# Android compilation failure in maven

Tags: maven, compiler-errors, android

I am making an Android app, and have created a custom view to do some animation.
I have created a custom view, extending ImageView and implementing ValueAnimator.AnimatorUpdateListener.

When I try to compile this with maven it fails with "package android.animation does not exist"
However, when building within Intellij Idea it builds fine. After building in Idea it is even possible to run mvn install successfully.
The successful build running fine in the emulator, but not on my physical device.
When trying to start it up on the device I get:

```
Failed resolving Lno/derp/myapp/view/MyAnimatedView; interface 7 'Landroid/animation/ValueAnimator$AnimatorUpdateListener;'
Link of class 'Lno/derp/myapp//view/MyAnimatedView;' failed
Could not find class 'no/derp/myapp/view/MyAnimatedView', referenced from method no/derp/myapp.MainActivity.onCreate
```

and then

```
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: no/derp/myapp.MyAnimatedView in loader dalvik.system.PathClassLoader[/data/app/no/derp/myapp-2.apk]
```

pom.xml:

```
 <packaging>apk</packaging>
 <name>My App</name>

 <dependencies>
   <dependency>
     <groupId>com.google.android</groupId>
     <artifactId>android</artifactId>
     <version>2.3.3</version>
     <scope>provided</scope>
   </dependency>
 </dependencies>

<build>
  <plugins>
    <plugin>
      <groupId>com.jayway.maven.plugins.android.generation2</groupId>
      <artifactId>android-maven-plugin</artifactId>
      <version>3.0.0</version> 
      <configuration>
        <androidManifestFile>${project.basedir}/AndroidManifest.xml</androidManifestFile>
        <assetsDirectory>${project.basedir}/assets</assetsDirectory>
        <resourceDirectory>${project.basedir}/resources</resourceDirectory>
      <undeployBeforeDeploy>true</undeployBeforeDeploy>
    </configuration>
    <extensions>true</extensions>
  </plugin>

  <plugin>
    <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.3.2</version>
    <configuration>
        <target>1.6</target>
        <source>1.6</source>
    </configuration>
  </plugin>
</plugins>
```

I am using the latest version of the SDK. A class importing the mentioned package does not compile, it is not just the view. The same happens with version 2.8.3 of android-maven-plugin (or maven-android-plugin as it was called)

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[android.animation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/animation/package-summary.html) is available since API Level 11, you need set your dependency in your pom.xml to use 3.0+ to compile your code in command-line.

The reason why it works in Intellij is IDE usually use default.properties to resolve the SDK used to compile source code, I suppose you use the correct API level in your default.properties.

Hope this help.

Answer (score 1):

It seems you are missing the configuration of the plugin for the platform/api level. Check out e.g. [helloflashlight example](https://github.com/jayway/maven-android-plugin-samples/blob/master/helloflashlight/pom.xml) of the official samples.

In your case you would have to add

```
                <sdk>
                    <!-- platform or api level (api level 4 = platform 1.6)-->
                    <platform>4</platform>
                </sdk>
```

with api level 9 or 10 or whatever you need. See the [API level doc](http://developer.android.com/guide/appendix/api-levels.html).

And for the compile plugin to have the right API you have to have the correct android dependency. You potentially have to use my [Maven Android SDK Deployer](https://github.com/mosabua/maven-android-sdk-deployer) to push the dependency into your local repository

Comment: <sdk> ..</sdk> Does not have any effect. I have only api level 14 installed, so unless I put platform 14 there it complains that I do not have the correct SDK installed. Setting it to 14 has no effect.

Comment: Running Maven Android SDK Deployer did however have an effect, installing the android:android:4.0_r2 into my repository.

Answer (score 0):

Maven Android SDK Deployer helped since I got

```
  <dependency>
      <groupId>android</groupId>
      <artifactId>android</artifactId>
      <version>4.0_r2</version>
      <scope>provided</scope>
  </dependency>
```

But the application still crashes on my phone, same as before, "Link of .. failed". Which is natural, since I probably have Android 2.X on my phone.
The reason Idea compiles is because it has the Android SDK set manually, it does not use the maven plugin, I think.

Comment: well. of course if you are not running API 11 or higher on your phone you can not use API's from it unless you use reflection. That has nothing to do with the build.